# Rails NameError in controller / undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add items to a cart. I keep getting

> Undefined local variable or method `document_id' for #<Cart:0x8fc0130>
>   Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/technical_library
>   app/models/cart.rb:22:in`add_item'
>   app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:7:in `add_to_cart' Request
>   Parameters:
>   {"_method"=>"post",

```
cart.rb
has_many :items
  def add_item(product_id)
    $test1 = 'add item 2'
    item = items.where('document_id = ?', document_id).first
    if item
      increase the quantity of product in cart
     item.quantity + 1
      save
    else
      product does not exist in cart
      product = Product.find(product_id)
      items << product
           document = Document.find(document_id)
           items << document

      cart.items << Item.new(document_id: document_id)

    end
    save
  end
```

Application controller:

```
application_controller.rb
  def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end
```

.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

carts controller:

```
  def add_to_cart
    # @cart = current_cart
    current_cart.add_item(params[:document_id])
    redirect_to carts_path(current_cart.id)
    # redirect to shopping cart or whereever
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
   post '/add_to_cart/:doc_id' => 'carts#add_to_cart', :as => 'add_to_cart'
```

Schema:

```
 create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "document_id"
    t.string   "user"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "items", ["cart_id"], name: "index_items_on_cart_id"


create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I am calling the add action with the following link in my documents.index

```
<td><%= link_to "add",  add_to_cart_path(document.id), :method => :post %></td>
```

Comment: you highlight line 22. the offending line? We lost that information here.

Comment: There is missing `document_id` parameter in the `add_item` method. Also you passing in the controller `params[:document_id]` as `product_id` parameter of this method.

Comment: You're passing 'document.id' to the 'add-item' method, which then assigns it to 'product_id'.  Then, in that 'add-item' method, you try to look up the item by the variable 'document_id', which doesn't exist in the 'add-item' method, because you haven't defined it and assigned it a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = items.where('document_id = ?', document_id).first
```

On that line document_id is not defined.  should that actually be product_id?

Comment: It should be document_id. I got sloppy transposing some code that was using product_id..

Comment: Well then you need to define document_id.  perhaps document_id = params[:document_id]?

Comment: That definitely got me on the right track. I have to get the exact syntax now. For example, if I'm writing   `cart.item.document_id << Item.new(document_id: document_id)`  I need to to define cart and item with something like:.. ie ` item = Item.first` and `cart = Cart.first` . Of course, the definition will be more like the params you outlined above.